# why does the score keep counting after gameover?

Tags: processing

Everything works perfectly as it should except the fact that even when the person has lost the game, the score keeps counting. The score should freeze when the game is lost so that when the method gameover (); is called the score can be given for that game.

It also does not add a specific amount, the score just raises from 10 to 210 to 430 - it just all over the place.
Can someone find the reason for it?

```java
    // variables for the ball
    int ball_width = 15, 
      ball_height = 15; 

    float ballX, 
      ballY;

    // // variables for the paddles
    int paddle_width = 20, 
      paddle_height = 200;

    int paddle1, 
      paddle2=0; 

    // // direction variables 
    float  directionX = 12, 
      directionY = 12; 

    // // variables for the score
    int scorecounter = 0;

    // //game states
    boolean playing = false, 
      gameover = false, 
      finalscore = false, 
      score = true;


    // ----------------------------------------------------

    void setup () {

      size (1900, 800); // the field game is going to be 1900x800 px big
      background (0); // black background
      rectMode (CENTER);

      paddle1 = 60;
      paddle2 = width - 60;
    }

    void draw () {

      background (0); // black background

      playing ();
      contact ();
      gameover ();
    } 

    // ----------------------------------------------------

    void playing () {

      if (keyPressed) {  // starts the game and makes the restart possible
        playing = true;
        scorecounter = 0 ;
        gameover = false;
        ballX = width/2;
        ballY = height/2;
      }

      if (!playing) {
        // playing = false

        fill(255); 
        textSize(80); 
        textAlign(CENTER); 
        text("Press Space to Play", width/2, height/4);

        fill (255); 
        ellipse (width/2, height/2, ball_width, ball_height); // this is the starting point of the ball
        fill (255, 10, 20); 
        rect(paddle1, (height/2), paddle_width, paddle_height);  // red pong
        fill (60, 255, 0); 
        rect(paddle2, (height/2), paddle_width, paddle_height);  // green pong
      }

      if (playing) { // playing = true

        score(); // does what i wrote down in void score () -- keeps track of the score

        ballX = ballX + directionX;
        ballY = ballY + directionY; // gives the directions of the ball

        fill (255); 
        ellipse (ballX, ballY, ball_width, ball_height); // ball itself

        fill ( 255, 10, 20 ); 
        rect(paddle1, mouseY, paddle_width, paddle_height); // red pong

        fill ( 60, 255, 0 ); 
        rect(paddle2, mouseY, paddle_width, paddle_height);  // green pong

        // top and bottom of screen --------------------
        if ( ballY  + ball_width/2 > height ) { 
          directionY = -directionY;
        } // if the ball reaches the lower wall it will bounce off

        if ( ballY - ball_width/2 < 0 ) { 
          directionY = -directionY;
        } // if the ball reaches the upper wall it will bounce off

        if ( ballX > width || ballX < 0 ) { 
          gameover = true;
        } // if the ball reaches one of the bounderies it will be game over
      }
    }

    void contact () {

      // right paddle = paddle2 
      if (ballY - ball_width/2 > mouseY - paddle_height/2 && 
        ballY + ball_width/2 < mouseY + paddle_height/2 && 
        ballX + ball_width/2 > paddle2-4 ) {
        directionX = -abs(directionX);
        scorecounter = scorecounter + 10;
      }

      // left paddle = paddle1
      if (ballY - ball_width/2 > mouseY - paddle_height/2 && 
        ballY + ball_width/2 < mouseY + paddle_height/2 && 
        ballX + ball_width/2 < paddle1+ paddle_width+4 ) {
        directionX = abs(directionX);
        scorecounter = scorecounter + 10; // if the ball touches the paddles it will bounce off
      }

      score ();
    }

    void gameover () {

      if (gameover) {
        background (0);
        finalscore (); // gives me the final score + play again option
        score = false;
      } // it overrides the scorecounter with a black background

    } 

    void score () {

      if (playing) {

        fill(255); 
        textSize(45); 
        textAlign(CENTER); 
        text ( scorecounter, width/2, height/4); // keeps the score on the display while playing
      }

    }

    void finalscore () {

      if (gameover) {

        score = false; // the scorecounter will stop counting

        fill(255); 
        textSize(45); 
        textAlign(CENTER); 
        text("Game Over. Press a key to play again.", width/2, height/4); // game over message
        fill(255); 
        textSize(80); 
        textAlign(CENTER); 
        text("You scored " + scorecounter+ " points", width/2, (height/4) * 3); // the final score will appear here
      }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use SO for replacement of debugging. if you get stuck edit your question to ask question with a minimal verifiable representation of a problem. Make an effort yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 
`playing = false;`
somewhere in game over method or somewhere else. As I see you haven't such line of code.
I ask a question. Where did you change playing to false so that 
You expect to get

```
 If(!playing)
```

Condition instead of

```
If(playing)
```

You press the key. Game begins. Now you reach

```
If(playing)
```

Then the ball get to boundaries and the code reach

```
 if ( ballX > width || ballX < 0 ) {
gameover = true; } // if the ball reaches one of the bounderies it will be game over
```

In this situation. Playing var and gameover var both are true. Right?
And under

```
If(playing)
```

You have score() method.so even when gameover is true the score method still is performed.

You can set playing to false under:

```
if ( ballX > width || ballX < 0 ) {     gameover = true;
Playing =false ; }
```

Or you can modify the score method like this:

```
 void score () { if (playing && !gameover) { fill(255); textSize(45); textAlign(CENTER); text(scorecounter, width/2,height/4); 
// keeps the score on the display  while playing }
```

Comment: that was exactly what the problem was. thank you so much!! @klaymen